# NoMethodError when trying to do Test Driven Development in Ruby

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to do TDD in Ruby with a simple recursive Factorial. I am trying to just run a simple test but I keep running into a NoMethodError. I was wondering what I am doing wrong?

Here is my factorial_test.rb

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './factorial.rb'

class FactorialTest < MiniTest::Test
  describe Factorial do
    it "should provide factorial of 1 as 1" do
      factorial(1).must_equal 1
    end
  end
end
```

and here is my factorial.rb

```
class Factorial 
  def factorial(number)
    1
  end
end
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
`NoMethodError: undefined method `factorial' for #<#<Class:0x007fbaa5962d70>:0x007fbaa584a758>`
```

I even tried adding a setup part to my factorial_test.rb like so:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './factorial.rb'

class FactorialTest < MiniTest::Test
  def setup
    @factorial = Factorial.new
  end

  describe Factorial do
    it "should provide factorial of 1 as 1" do
      factorial.factorial(1).must_equal 1
    end
  end
end
```

But I end up with a NameError:

```
`NameError: undefined local variable or method `factorial' for #<#<Class:0x007fc0e8996fc8>:0x007fc0e90ef1f8>`
```

If anyone can please help me out, I would appreciate it!

EDIT:

Applying the fix from the suggestions below:

```
describe Factorial do
    it "should provide factorial of 1 as 1" do
      @factorial.factorial(1).must_equal 1
    end
  end
```

I get a different error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `factorial' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am initializing the factorial class?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an instance variable:

```
def setup
    @factorial = Factorial.new
end
```

But you are calling your test on a local variable:

```
it "should provide factorial of 1 as 1" do
     factorial.factorial(1).must_equal 1
end
```

Try calling the test on the instance variable you created:

```
it "should provide factorial of 1 as 1" do
    @factorial.factorial(1).must_equal 1
end
```

:]

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct was on the right track!

`#factorial` is an instance method, so it needs to be called on an instance (aka `Factorial.new`).

Your change to set `@factorial = Factorial.new` in the setup method was the right thing to do, now you just need to call the method on `@factorial`:

```
@factorial.factorial(1).must_equal 1
```

You're getting `undefined local variable or method 'factorial'` because the variable is named `@factorial`, not just `factorial`.  You need the `@`!

Comment: Thank you! I got passed that error, but I am getting a new error where it says `NoMethodError: undefined method `factorial' for nil:NilClass` when I apply the fix. Am I setting it up correctly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've figured it out by now, but you should call you setup method so that the instance variable is set, then you can call methods on that instance variable.